# Find correlation between two columns

Tags: r, correlation

I am working on the housing price challenge from Kaggle and I'm looking into whether there is a correlation between the two exterior siding combinations.

When I setup my initial statement, listed below, it returns the correlation just between the columns as a whole. What I'm curious about is whether there is a difference between (Exterior1st = VinySd & Exterior2nd = MetalSd) vs (Exterior1st = BrkFace & Exterior2nd = MetalSd).

```
ext_correlation <- cor(train[,c(82,83,75)],use="everything")
```

Comment: The last sentence before the code is unclear, at least to me. Could you further elaborate? Also edit to add a sample of the data or use a built in data set eg Boston Housing(not sure if it's builtin though).

Comment: The two "exterior" variables are both nominal, i.e. categorical variables without any inherent ordering, so correlation isn't really the right method here.

Comment: @NelsonGon, suppose that house with both vinyl & metal siding had a larger impact on pricing than say houses with a combination of brick and metal siding.

Comment: @gersht, if correlation isn't the correct method for this can you suggest one that I can research?  Also, what if I converted to the column to numerical?

Comment: A correlation tells us that an increase/decrease in one variable is associated with an increase/decrease in another variable. How are you going to represent a change in exterior as an increase/decrease? Converting to numeric won't fix this problem because the resulting integers would be be based on alphabetical order and not inherent quality/price/etc.

Comment: Use a contingency table with `table()` to examine the co-occurence of categorical variables. You can test for independence using the chi-squared test `chisq.test()` or Fisher's exact test `fisher.test()`. That said, I don't think they will help you much because the exteriors in question don't co-occur at all, i.e. their cell values are 0.

Comment: It would probably make the most sense to compute regression models, using the "exterior" variables as interaction terms. For instance, if you try something like `lm(price ~ square_feet:exterior, data = train)` you might see that certain exteriors are associated with higher prices for every square footage.

Comment: One more thing: I only briefly looked at the data, but I think the line of inquiry dealing with combinations of exteriors is a dead end. The problem is that each exterior co-occurs the most with itself – i.e. metal siding with metal siding, wood shingles with wood shingles, etc. – and very little with other exteriors. I think the difference between the exteriors – vinyl vs. metal vs. wood – will likely produce more enlightening results.